# Is it a good practice to use "const auto&" in a range for to process the elements of std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm reading a code from *C++ Primer 5th (6.2.6. Functions with Varying Parameters)*:

```
void error_msg(ErrCode e, initializer_list<string> il)
{
    cout << e.msg() << ": ";
    for (const auto &elem : il)
        cout << elem << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

I always use `auto` directly in a range `for`. like this:

```
for (auto &elem : il)
```

But I never saw `const auto&` before.I know that the elements in an `initializer_list` are always **const values**. Is it the reason to use `const auto&`?

- What's the difference between this way and my old way?
- Is it a good practice to use "const auto&" in this case?

Comment: In c++17, you'll be able to do `for (elem : il)`. It's my preference, since it's easy to write and just works ([this syntax can already be tested on some compilers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaece67f80ac3577)).

Comment: @pepper_chico Wow, It's really cool!

Comment: `for (auto elem : il)` will unnecessarily create a temporary copy of each element.

Comment: @SiyuanRen You mean we should use `for (auto &elem : il)` in range `for` statement as much as possible? such as print all the elements.

Comment: @pezy: It's not "really cool". It may be "really cool" in some other language but it violates a whole bunch of long-standing C++ paradigms and results in a totally inconsistent language that does not know what it wants to be.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: motivate

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What is the problem with the `for(e:r)` proposal?

Comment: @sp2danny: It violates a whole bunch of long-standing C++ paradigms and results in a totally inconsistent language that does not know what it wants to be.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm curious to know what paradigms are those, since c++ is multi-paradigm to the last. LOL

Comment: @pepper_chico: "multi" is not the same as "omni".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes. And C++ is not behaving as working around a fixed set of paradigms, it's more towards "open to anything that may be useful, present and future", than closed in its own fixed set of ideals. Besides this, which I'm not interested discussing, you didn't answer both questions, what's wrong with `for(e:r)` and what are such long-standing C++ paradigms that it violates.

Comment: @pepper_chico: No you're right I opted not to because it would take a blog article not a comment :) Perhaps I'll write one some day.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess it would be an interesting read, maybe with potential for one of those top rants of HN.

Comment: That `for (e : r)` proposal got rejected for the time being and won't make it into C++17.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is a good practice because the intent is clear and prevent accidental changes to break your code.

The difference between the several forms of ranged base for loop:

- `for (auto elem : il)` will create a temporary copy of each element. Usually less efficient.
- `for (auto& elem: il)` won't create copies, and allow you to modify the elements if the underlying container allows that (e.g. not `const`). But it cannot bind to rvalue references, so it cannot be used on containers that return proxy objects (e.g. `std::vector<bool>`).
- `for (const auto& elem: il)` won't create copies either, and won't allow you to do any modifications. This can prevent accidental modifications and signify your intent clearly.
- `for (auto&& elem: il)` automatically deduces the correct type for `elem`, be it l-value, const l-value or r-value reference. A standard proposal [N3994](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm), already implemented by clang, simplify it into the form `for (elem: il)`.

Comment: In my opinion, the **intent** of first one is "don't change", second one is "if allowed, you can change".right? (so, if just print, we selected `for (auto elem : il)`.)

Comment: @pezy: If you just need to print, why do you make a copy?

Comment: Yep. But almost all the print code use `for (auto elem : arr)` in *C++ Primer 5th*, Why? What's the point?

Comment: @pezy: In the exact location where `for (auto elem : arr)` appears in *C++ primer 5th*, the type of `elem` is `int`. `int` is cheap to copy, while `std::string` is not.

Comment: Whoa, didnt know about that proposal. Really nice they are simplifying the language. Although, I'd prefer if they defaulted to const (that goes for lambda capture  by reference as well).

Answer (score 22):

Since the elements of an `std::initializer_list` are `const`, iterating with `auto& elem` and `const auto& elem` have the same semantics. The advantage of writing the `const` is that it makes it explicit to anyone reading the code that the contents will not be modified (even though it's not possible to modify the contents anyway).

Comment: Thx for answer, you mean adding `const` only for readability? so I also can do it like that: `const auto elem : il`? Is still the same?

Comment: @pezy `const` has a different meaning when iterating by value. Think about pass by value and pass by reference for functions and it'll make sense.

Answer (score 3):

For me it is good:

- Makes it explicit.
- Redundancy in this case is eliminated by the compiler.
- If you replace by another container, you will still have const, will not be silently modified.